# find a local max/min of a function with $\frac{f(x+\varepsilon)}{f(x-\varepsilon)}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, optimization

I was solving a problem that asked to estimate the value of $N$ in an event whose probability was given by:
$$\mathbb{P}(N)=\frac{\binom{N-100}{90}\binom{100}{10}}{\binom{N}{100}}$$
i.e., the question asked to find a reasonable local maximum of $\mathbb{P}(N)$. As this function is too complicated, the hint given was to consider when $\frac{\mathbb{P}(N+1)} {\mathbb{P}(N)}=1$, since, as $\mathbb{P}(N)$ is always positive and, if it has a maximum at $N_0$, then, intuitively, at some points in the neighborhood of $N_0$, $\mathbb{P}$ would reach equal values. In fact, the problem simplifies a lot, since
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(N+1)} {\mathbb{P}(N)}=\frac{(N-99)^2}{(N-189)(N+1)}$$
which is $1$ if $N = 999$, very close to the local maximum.

After researching further, I was unable to find any reference about finding maxima and minima in this way, so I tried to prove an analogous statement that would justify the process: If $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta<\varepsilon$ such that
$$\frac{f(x_0+\delta)}{f(x_0-\delta)}=1$$
with $x_0\in(a,b)$, then $x_0$ is a local maximum/minimum of $f$?

so my questions are:

- Is this process for finding local maxima and minima known? If so, where can I find references to learn more about it?
- If not, is my attempt to justify the method valid? If so, how do I prove it? and what would be another good explanation/theorem that justifies the process?

Comment: Rolles theorem may be useful here

Comment: oh, I see, so taking $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ and $\delta<\varepsilon$ we have that there's always a $c_\delta$, with $x_0-\delta<c_\delta<x_0+\delta$ such that $f'(c_\delta)=0$, by squeeze, when $n\to\infty$, $c_\delta\to x_0$, and since $f$ is differentiable $f'(x_0)=0$, does this work? @fGDu94

Comment: Push epsilon to zero

Comment: I edited the message @fGDu94, see now

Comment: Looks good but leave open to discussion